# Quickbooks online API with oauth2

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, quickbooks

I need to use Quickbooks online API to synchronize data between my system and my client's accounts on quickbooks.

I need to know if is it possible to complete the oauth2 authorization flow and make API calls without human interaction (without the need to interact with Intuit's authentication and authorization windows)?

I read the Intuit's docs on: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000500_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app

On the first step, I made a GET request to:

```
https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=MY_ID&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FMY_NGROK_URL.ngrok.io%2FOAuth2PHPExample.php&response_type=code&state=RandomState#/Authorize/COMPANY_ID
```

Then, the Intuit's authentication and authorization windows opens and I need to put my username and password and then, click in the authorize button to get the authorization code.

Is there a way to obtain the authorization code without authenticate and authorize?

I need to automate this task to make API calls in the backend with PHP.

Thanks,
Marcelo.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to obtain the authorization code without authenticate and authorize?

No... but read below.

> I need to automate this task to make API calls in the backend with PHP.

You are misunderstanding how OAuth (either 1 or 2) works.

The *very first time you connect* you will be prompted to authenticate/authorize access to the QuickBooks Online data.

You are then given a refresh token (or access token depending on if you're using OAuth2 vs. OAuth1).

You then *store that refresh token* (or access token for OAuth1) and can use that token going forward to make your requests, unattended, without requiring the user to be involved at all.

Key take-away: *You only need the user involved the VERY FIRST TIME you connect, and then never again.*

Comment: Thanks Keith! Now I understand how oauth works. I thought there was a way to call the APIs without authenticate.