# how to make an quickbooks Api call and bypass login

Tags: oauth-2.0, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I know I'm probably going to get a "no, you can't do that" but it doesn't seem reasonable to me.

My client uses Quickbooks Online and wants to be able to have his customers sign in to his web site and see how much they owe, and then pay their invoices with a credit card.

Obviously, the customers themselves can't be signing into Quickbooks Online.  We want the web server to be able to directly access the data via the api.

I've found the api but I'm not sure if it's possible to have the webserver connecting to it and getting the data it needs.

I know this can be done with other systems.  I've done it with GMail and Salesforce using OAuth2.

The biggest piece I want to load from quickbooks as well might be something unavailable as I couldn't find it in the API anywhere.   When my client opens Quickbooks Online, he can send an email to any customer that will include a link to pay online by credit card.  We'd like to be able to find that link and redirect the user to it.  But I'm not sure if it's available via the api.

I could go with webhooks but that would require storing all that data on our webserver, and syncing it for existing data.  Not to mention what happens if an update happens to fail.

Comment: This is a near duplicate of this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509192/quickbooks-online-api-with-oauth2?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how OAuth works a bit, which is what is causing the confusion here.

The person who owns the QuickBooks company logs in, not the end-user. They log in ONCE, and that gets you OAuth tokens that you can use to make server-to-server calls forever going forward.

Soooo...

> I know I'm probably going to get a "no, you can't do that" but it doesn't seem reasonable to me.

You *can* do what you're trying to do, you're just going about it the wrong way.

> Obviously, the customers themselves can't be signing into Quickbooks Online.

Correct.

> We want the web server to be able to directly access the data via the api.

That's fine, and totally do-able.

> I've found the api but I'm not sure if it's possible to have the webserver connecting to it and getting the data it needs.

It is do-able.

The key understanding here is that you're going to have an OAuth connection process that the person who owns QuickBooks is going to go through just once, to get you OAuth tokens.

You're then going to store those OAuth tokens server-side (e.g. in your database).

You can then use those stored OAuth tokens to make future server-to-server API calls whenever you want.

> When my client opens Quickbooks Online, he can send an email to any customer that will include a link to pay online by credit card. We'd like to be able to find that link and redirect the user to it. But I'm not sure if it's available via the api.

I don't think this information is available via the API right now.

There is an API endpoint to send an email invoice, if that's helpful:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/invoice

Comment: Thanks Keith,  that helps a great deal.

Comment: Keith, you don't know of a sample on doing that, do you?  The intuit sample is somewhat convoluted.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: c# but I can understand php.  I'm just having weird issues trying to get the intuit sample working with it.  The basic login works but if I try to connect with the authorization code, I just get bad request responses.

Comment: Success, finally. I was able to refresh the access code.  What was happening was the intuit sample was properly refreshing the code, but then it was using the access code request, which was still a bad request from the call above.